# Operation name must be unique in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I´m having a trouble with a web service implementation in eclipse (mars, neon, oxygen..)

It does not correctly validate the name of the methods and recognizes them as if they were repeated

My sample class is this:

```
package servicios.ecobis.cobiscorp.negocio.admin.consulta.consultadianohabil.impl;    
.......    
@javax.jws.WebService (
        endpointInterface="servicios.ecobis.cobiscorp.negocio.admin.consulta.consultadianohabil.ConsultaDiaNoHabil", 
        targetNamespace="http://cobiscorp.ecobis.servicios/negocio/admin/consulta/ConsultaDiaNoHabil/", 
        serviceName="ConsultaDiaNoHabil", 
        portName="ConsultaDiaNoHabilSOAP"
)
public class ConsulaDiaNoHabilWSImpl implements Serializable{
    ......
    private String verificarRequestParamsID(ConsultarDiasNoHabilesPorAnioRequest consultarDiasNoHabilesPorAnioRequest){                 
        ......          
    }

    private void adicionarRequestParamsID(ServiceRequestTO requestCTS, ConsultarDiasNoHabilesPorAnioRequestBody body) {                 
        ......          
    }

    private String verificarRequestParamsID(ValidarDiaNoHabilRequest validarDiaNoHabilRequest){         
        ......          
    }

    private void adicionarRequestParamsID(ServiceRequestTO requestCTS, ValidarDiaNoHabilRequestBody body) {             
        .......         
    }

}
```

Eclipse shows this error:

```
Operation names must be unique :'{http://cobiscorp.ecobis.servicios/negocio/admin/consulta/ConsultaDiaNoHabil/}adicionarRequestParamsID'    ConsulaDiaNoHabilWSImpl.java    /WSAdmin/src/servicios/ecobis/cobiscorp/negocio/admin/consulta/consultadianohabil/impl  line 292    Annotation Problem
```

[image: Error Eclipse]

I have found [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=470101) bug reported in eclipse but it seems without solution

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In IBM Rational Application Developer v7.5.5 this code works fine

Comment: I have already disabled the Annotation Processing in the project properties and it works but I'm not sure if it is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this [issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=470101) pending for a long time.

As a workaround for the time being, you can disable the Annotation Processing in the Project Properties.

> Right Click on Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> Annotation Processing

Here is the screenshot below:

[image: Annotation Processing]